# Pass an expression that I want to evaluate as parameter to PHP function

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that is supposed return corresponding list of values for given input. Here is its code:

```
function output_values($s, $e, $d, $exp = '$i*$i') {
  for($i = $s; $i <= $e; $i+= $d) {
    echo eval($exp);
    // Put the value of $i in $exp and get the result.
  }
}
```

The expression will always be mathematical like `$i*$i` or `3*$i + 8` etc.

I got the following error with it:

```
syntax error, unexpected end of file in eval()'d code
```

I know that I can use `array_map()`. However, that function still requires me to pass the expression myself. In this case, I won't know the expression whose value I need to evaluate beforehand.

I hope I am making it clear.

Thanks.

Comment: No, not really clear. Give a proper example of what such an expression might look like. Are you trying to pass some condition in string form, or what exactly?

Comment: @CBroe I have added two examples. :)

Comment: Your basic options are `eval` (dangerous), or to write your own expression parser.

Comment: To pass “code” as argument, you’d pass a *function* (probably an anonymous function written inline) and call it inside your function to evaluate it and get its return value.

Comment: @deceze Could you please show me an example?

Comment: @CBroe I tried `eval` and got an error about unexpected end of file.

Comment: You need an `;` at the end of your expression - `$i*$i;` But that would still not get you any _result_, if you eval'd it - you'd need to make it something like `$result = $i*$i;`, so that you can access it via that variable afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass an expression, or any *code* in general, use [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php):

```
function output_values($s, $e, $d, callable $exp) {
  for ($i = $s; $i <= $e; $i += $d) {
    echo $exp($i);
  }
}

output_values(1, 6, 2, fn ($i) => $i * $i);
```

Comment: Thanks @deceze. :)

Does the callback keyword serve an actual purpose or it is just to help me keep in mind that $exp is actually a function.

Comment: It just enforces type checking and serves as documentation, never a bad idea to have it.